# when is a highchart completely loaded?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I saw this code: http://jsfiddle.net/AVygG/

I'm curious when is the point that the highchart gets loaded completely? I saw in highcharts documentation that *events: load:* should do the magic of being able to call the callback function when the highchart is completely loaded.

If it were completely loaded, then could I assume that *var chart* should already have the values when the alert pops? Is that a good basis that the chart is already loaded?

The reason I asked is that I'm working on another code that the highchart apparently doesn't get loaded completely in IE8. Looks like highcharts is potentially having a race condition on the loading of its elements.

Thanks!

```
$(function () {
// create the chart
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            load: function(event) {
                alert ('Chart loaded');
            }
        }        
    },
    xAxis: {
    },

    series: [{
        animation: false,
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]     
    }]
});
```

});
​

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem that you are having in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 25):

Highcharts has callback function

```
 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            events: {
                redraw: function(event) {
                    alert ('Chart loaded');
                }
            }        
        },
        series: [{
            animation: false,
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]     
        }]
    },function(chart){

alert('LOADED');

});
```

Comment: is there something like on animation start?

Answer (score 8):

Try with the `redraw` event. This event is triggered after loading, but also after the series was added and chart resizing.

```
$(function () {
    // create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            events: {
                redraw: function(event) {
                    alert ('Chart loaded');
                }
            }        
        },
        series: [{
            animation: false,
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]     
        }]
    });
});
```

Redraw event from offical Highcharts reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-redraw/

Comment: and where did you left type?

Answer (score 8):

In the load callback function, you can access the chart object by using "this" pointer.

```
        events: {
            load: function(event) {
                alert ('Chart loaded with series :'+ this.series[0].name);
                console.log(this);
            }
        }
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/msjaiswal/AVygG/25/

Comment: how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/AVygG/97/ The callback function triggers earlier than expected.

Answer (score 3):

This was answered, but not clearly enough imo. Highcharts documentation says

> ... In most cases the chart is built in one thread, but in Internet
> Explorer version 8 or less the chart is sometimes initiated before the
> document is ready, and in these cases the chart object will not be
> finished directly after calling `new Highcharts.Chart()`. As a
> consequence, code that relies on the newly built Chart object should
> always run in the callback.

So, dealing with the chart object in IE8 *must be done* in the callback, i.e. `new Highcharts.Chart(options, function(chart) { ... })`. You can also use `function() { ... }` and use `this` in the function.

In regards to your specific concern re a loading message. I had to do it in the callback, but it works.

```
chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options, function(){
  this.showLoading();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In angular project I had to use `setTimeout()` function to get width working properly as below:

```
setTimeout(()=>this.chart.reflow())
```

Comment: Ys, seems like in Angular callback function doesn't have a complete chart object. I have to use timeout to apply zoom to it. The delay is about 800 milliseconds. A lot.

Comment: @Mark How did you come up it 800 ms? Just curios

Comment: Simply by experimenting. However, I have moved my code into load event, now I dont have that problem with resetting zoom.

Answer (score 0):

in Polymer 3 I had to use **window.setTimeout()** function to get width working properly as below.`load: function() { window.setTimeout(() => { this.reflow(); }, 1); },`