# GWT Highcharts calling Javascript using JSNI

Tags: gwt, highcharts, jsni, gwt-highcharts

I am writing a GWT application and using highcharts. Some features are not implementable in Java but are in javascript. I was given an example of how to implement something I can use however, I do not know how to included in my code.

My code includes a variable declared as `Chart graph;`

I would like to implement an event as show in this answer [Add tooltip to legend in highcharts when hovering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137466/add-tooltip-to-legend-in-highcharts-when-hovering)

```
  chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var chart = this,
                    legend = chart.legend;

                for (var i = 0, len = legend.allItems.length; i < len; i++) {
                    var item = legend.allItems[i].legendItem;
                    item.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                        //show custom tooltip here
                        console.log("mouseover");
                    }).on('mouseout', function (e) {
                        //hide tooltip
                        console.log("mouseout");
                    });
                }

            }
        }

    },
```

How would add this capability to my code. I tried using the chart.setOption(/chart/events/load", Object o) as shown here http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/apidocs/index.html but I could not figure a way to do it.

I assume it will be accomplished by creating a method

```
private native void foo(JavaScriptObject c)/*-{


}-*/;
```

OR

```
private native void foo(Chart c)/*-{


}-*/;
```

but I am unsure how to connect the two. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by "using highcharts"? are you using the GWT wrapped version by moxiegroup? is it simply included as a JS resource and you're wrapping only the necessary calls by yourself? is the highcharts API in your project exposed entirely in java?

Comment: Yes, I am using the GWT wrapped version by moxiegroup. To my understanding yes, the highcharts API is exposed entirely in java, but there are some things that aren't in it that I would like to add.

Answer (score 1):

First create a native method like this;

```
private native void foo(JavaScriptObject chart)/*-{
    var legend = chart.legend;

    for (var i = 0, len = legend.allItems.length; i < len; i++) {
        var item = legend.allItems[i].legendItem;

        item.on('mouseover', function (e) {
            //show custom tooltip here
            console.log("mouseover");
        }).on('mouseout', function (e) {
            //hide tooltip
            console.log("mouseout");
        });
    }
}-*/;
```

And then call this method in conjunction with `setLoadEventHandler()` like this;

```
chart.setLoadEventHandler(new ChartLoadEventHandler() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLoad(ChartLoadEvent chartLoadEvent) {
            foo(chart.getNativeChart());

            return true;
        }
    });
```

And that's all! Hope this will help you.