# add message on hover series name highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

i'm trying to add a message when hover a series name and i just cant find the way to do it,
this is what i want want to happen: 
[image]

when the user hover the "all your locations" series name the red box will apear.
as for now the only way i found to do it is to search div contains the same words but its a really bad practice and im pretty sure there is a better way to do it..
is it possible to do it via highcharts ?

Answer (score 1):

A popup like that is not in the Highchart API for the legend. The closet thing is Legend.ItemOnHover

```
legend: {
            itemHoverStyle: {
                color: '#FF0000'
            }
        }
```

But that really only styles it.

The way you are currently doing it is probably fine if you are careful about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add tooltip to the legend item, like in the related topic [Add tooltip to legend in highcharts when hovering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137466/add-tooltip-to-legend-in-highcharts-when-hovering/16168110#16168110)

Answer (score 0):

the only way i have found to do this popup is by adding this function in the end of the function building the chart :

```
    var titles = $("tspan");
$("tspan").each(function(index) {
    if( (this.textContent.indexOf("cashiers data") !== -1) ){
        $(titles[index]).click(function(){
            alert('to use our new cashiers bars \n'
                 +'please contact us at our contact page');
            return false;
        })
    }
});
```