# Add custom tooltip to Legend in Highcharts when hovering

Tags: jquery, highcharts, tooltip, legend

I'm trying to add text to my Legends using the build in tooltip (or custom ones, it does'nt have to be build in) but I can't get it to work. For example one of my legends is called 'Heat production' and when the user hovers over that legend I need a tooltip to appear with an explanation on what Heat production means. I have six legends that I need to attach tooltips to.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137466/add-tooltip-to-legend-in-highcharts-when-hovering) was somewhat useful but when I go

```
item.text
```

... inside the for-loop in the 'mouseover' function, all the legends get the text of the last legend. This means that I am unable to identify the legend and add text to be displayed to it. Here is the code from the above answer with mine added in the console.log():

```
events: {
        load: function () {
            var chart = this,
                legend = chart.legend;

            for (var i = 0, len = legend.allItems.length; i < len; i++) {
                var item = legend.allItems[i].legendItem;
                item.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                    //show custom tooltip here
                    console.log(item.text);
                }).on('mouseout', function (e) {
                    //hide tooltip
                    console.log(item.text);
                });
            }

        }
    }
```

To sum up:
How can I grab all the Legends in the for-loop and add a tooptip (containing a explanation from some hidden div) to it. I hope my problem formulation makes sense, but if it doesn't, just tell me and I will try to be more clear.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137466/add-tooltip-to-legend-in-highcharts-when-hovering/16168110#16168110