# HighCharts Legend Tool-Tip in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, tooltip

Is there a way to show a customized tool-tip for each legend item when you scroll over them. 
I need to display custom descriptions for each legend to describe the item however, adding it directly to the legend would make the title too long and the points tool-tip as well. So Instead the best approach would be to add a tool-tip to the legend that would display the description of the legend item. 
I can't seem to find anything in the documentation and most of the solutions I encounter don't seem to be fit for this case or Angular.

Comment: Check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37618597/4868839)

Comment: He's using JQuery to set the tooltip. I don't quite know how to achieve that in angular. I tried using getElementsByClassName to work over the HTMLCollection but that didn't work either. Apply matToolTip to the Span directly doesn't do anything either.

Comment: U don't wanna use jquery? Then u need to create a JavaScript func to achieve the same. Mattooltip sadly won't work, I've tried before..

Comment: I see thank you, I'll find an alternative